# Append 2 menus into 1 hamburger

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to append my main Nav menu and a top menu into one Hamburger menu when on mobile site. This is done by a toggle which works fine and as intended until I add the 3 lines to try and append the 2 menu bars. After searching and looking I can find no information on how to do this. The code that I have tried is shown below and this has also raised issues which I don't really know how to solve.

Firstly it is causing the Fiddle and the web page to crash. I am guessing looking at the next issue that it is just repeatedly appending.

The rightTop menu is being appended to the Hamburger menu (.menu ul) and each sub and sub sub menu. It is also appended in the .hamburger div when this is made active. This should not be the case and it should be appended just once in the top level of the Hamburger Menu.

Also when rightTop menu is appended it keeps its existing styling etc. How do I make this adopt the .menu ul styling and applicable CSS?

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ctmbu5r3/2/

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#toggle-nav').click(toggleNav);

    function toggleNav(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.hamburger ul').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('.dimmer').toggleClass('active');
        jQuery('body').toggleClass('no-scrolling');

        var $rightTop = $('.rightTop');
        $rightTop.appendTo('.menu ul');
        jQuery('.hamburger ul').addClass('BothNav');

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.top
{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.topWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    position:relative;
    background-color: black;
    flex: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
.rightTop
{
    flex-grow: 1;  
    order: 2;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.rightTop > ul
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.rightTop > ul > li
{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.rightTop > ul > li:not(:last-of-type)
{
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.rightTop > ul > li > a
{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 0px 16px;
}

.rightTop > ul > li > a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline; 
    color: white;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

.main
{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: white;
    flex: 1;    
}

/*NAVIGATION MENUS*/
.nav
{
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/*HORIZONTAL MENU*/
.menu
{
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu ul.navList
{
  list-style: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: -60%;
  background:blue;
  min-width: 60%;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu ul.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.menu > ul > li > a
{
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    color: white;
    padding:16px 16px 12px 16px;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent; /*To offset white underline hover*/
    font-weight: 700;
}

.menu > ul > li a:hover
{
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #F1F227;
    color: white;
    transition: 1s ease-out;
}

/*HAMBURGER*/
.hamburgerWrapper
{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.hamburger 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.hamburger.active
{
    left: 60%;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    padding-left: 70%;
}

.hamburger li a
{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 16px 15px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#toggle-nav:after {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: 'Menu';
}

#toggle-nav span, #toggle-nav span:before, #toggle-nav span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#toggle-nav span:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px; 
}
#toggle-nav span:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
}

#toggle-nav span, #toggle-nav span:before, #toggle-nav span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#toggle-nav.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before, #toggle-nav.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#toggle-nav.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-nav.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/*Sub Menu*/
.menu > ul > li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

.submenu
{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width : 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.submenu > li > a
{
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:16px 16px 12px 26px;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent; /*To offset white underline hover*/
    font-weight: 500;
}

.submenu > li:hover > a
{
  background-color: #062c6b;
  color: #FFDB00;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F1F227;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

/*Child Sub Menu*/
.menu > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul 
{
    display: block;
}

.subSubmenu
{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    bottom: 100%;
    /*top: 0;*/
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.subSubmenu > li > a
{
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    padding:19px 16px 12px 36px;
    border-bottom:4px solid transparent; /*To offset white underline hover*/
    font-weight: 300;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a
{
  background-color: red;
  color: #C5EFF7;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F1F227;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
}

/*COMBINE MENUS*/
.BothNav
{ 
  background:#506b97;
  z-index: 1;
}

/*Dimmer to dim background and no scolling when Hamburger menu is shown*/
.dimmer {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: none;
}

.dimmer.active 
{
  display: block;
}

body.no-scrolling 
{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="top">
<div class="topWrapper">
            <div class="rightTop">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">RightTop1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">RightTop2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">RightTop3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
<div class ="navWrapper">
<nav role="navigation" class="menu">  
    <div class="hamburgerWrapper">
        <ul class="hamburger">
            <li><a id="toggle-nav" href="#"><span></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="navList">
        <li><a href="#">NavMenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NavMenu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NavMenu3</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">NavMenu4</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub4</a>
                    <ul class="subSubmenu">
                        <li><a href="#">SubSub1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSub2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dimmer"></div>     
<div class="main">
<main role ="main" class="mainWrapper">
</main>
</div>
</div> 
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Javascript/JavaScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: As I have got no replies I am wondering if what I am trying to do is completely wrong and the wrong way to go about this? For instance am I better just to hide these 2 menu when mobile and instead display a 3rd 'when mobile menu' to combine what I want from both menus? I'd have thought this would be a fudge and a messy way to go about things....